# Visual Studio Load Tests : How can I use varying data in each test case invocation (without using a data source)?

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

Is there a "best practice" for doing this?

The best I have figured out is by implementing a LoadTest plugin, that sets up a TestContext property (string). The unit test can then generate something algorithmically off this value. And even so, multiple virtual users, and test agents, complicates things. I can only maintain a shared context for invocations that share the plugin instance.

Comment: Why is 'without using a data source' necessary?

Comment: Also... if you are already generating 'something algorithmically', can't you somehow involve the $WebTestUserId and the $AgentId in that algorithm to produce something unique for each user?  I assume by your mention of 'shared context' that you want to avoid duplicate data.  Is this crucial?  Would using a random number suffice?  If not, I return to wondering why you can't use a data source.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the best way is to have another C# library project to create LoadTest plugin with the data you queried from the database. In this way, the whole solution would have a library project and a performance test project. you reference the library project in the web performance test. And in the web performance test whereever you need  varying data, you use a load test plugin to get that data.